# Windows Script Host - неопознанная ошибка

Tags: vbscript, wsh

Взял небольшой пример из документации к InternetExplorer.Application:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Navigate "about:blank"

While IE.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 200
Wend

IE.Visible = 1
IE.Document.Write IE.StatusText
IE.StatusText = "ТЕКСТ СТРОКИ СОСТОЯНИЯ"
```

При запуске скрипта script.vbs двойным щелчком, появляется окно IE, и сразу ошибка:

```
Строка 10
Символ 1
Ошибка: Неопознанная ошибка
Код: 80004005
Источник: (null)
```

Если запускать из cmd cscript - тоже самое, запуск IE и ошибка в cmd

Система: Windows 10

Примечание, очень важное: на windows 7 работает, и доступ к DOM элементам страницы (тестировал со своей html страницей) есть.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, по-умолчанию статусбар отсутствует у окна IE для Windows 10.
Значит надо его включить.
Перед строкой показа окна браузера активируйте его. А после присвойте свойству текста нужное значение.

```
IE.StatusBar=true
IE.Visible = 1

IE.StatusText = "ТЕКСТ СТРОКИ СОСТОЯНИЯ"
```

P.S.
Возник дополнительный вопрос: зачем пытаться выводить в документ название текста статусбара?

```
IE.Document.Write IE.StatusText
```

P.S.S. Имейте в виду, что объект управления **IE** может некорректно отвечать при ошибочной отработке кода VBscript. Соответственно, автоматизация управлением Internet Explorer "зависнет".

Comment: Действительно, при инициализации statusbar заработало. Но теперь другая проблема. Этот же код не работает, если я указываю свою html страницу (по адресу http://localhost, локальный сервер xampp). И ещё не работает свойство ReadyState, при проверке while IE.ReadyState <> 4 WScript.Sleep 200 Wend появляется ошибка на строке IE.ReadyState <> 4 "Компьютер удалённого сервера не существует или недоступен". Так же при вызове метода IE.Refresh ошибка - Неопознанная ошибка

Comment: Всё заработало, когда вместо аргумента IE.Navigate "http://localhost" прописал "127.0.0.1"